# Is There a Limit on the Number of Rated Tournaments a Chess Player Can Attend in a Month?

Tags: fide, rating, tournament

I'm an enthusiastic chess player looking to participate in more rated tournaments to improve my ranking and gain experience. However, I'm curious if there's any sort of limitation on the number of rated tournaments a player can attend in a single month.

Does the FIDE (International Chess Federation) or any national chess federation impose restrictions on the frequency of participation in rated tournaments? Are there any rules or considerations regarding player fatigue, tournament integrity, or rating manipulation that would limit the number of tournaments one can play in a month?

Answer (score 2):

For FIDE you need to check [Rating Regulations](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022024).

I believe that there is no such limit, unless I interpret `3.1 There must be no more than 12 hours play in one day. This is calculated based on games that last 60 moves, although games played using increments may last longer.` wrongly. I believe this part only pertains to tournament organizers - that is, that no tournament should schedule so many rounds in one day, that play is expected to last more than 12 hours.

Anyway I think you will find it very impractical too attend so many tournaments monthly. Standard time control tournaments are in most countries organized only seldom, especially if you aren't a kid anymore (since then you cannot play in scholastic tournaments, which are the most common type). As such tournaments mean a big drain of time (read vacation days) and money (travel isn't cheap).

If you want regular OTB games check if chess association in your country/region or club organizes Leagues, they are a bit more practical.